# Why is my post controller returning a 404?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, controllers, routing

I've created and enabled a module at `app/code/Post/Test`:

`app/code/Post/Test/registration.php`:

```php
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Post_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/code/Post/Test/etc/module.xml`:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Post_Test" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

`app/code/Post/Test/etc/frontend/routes.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="post_test" frontName="posttest">
            <module name="Post_Test" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

`app/code/Post/Test/Controller/Test`:

```php
<?php

namespace Post\Test\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;

class Test implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    private $raw;

    public function __construct(Raw $raw)
    {
        $this->raw = $raw;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->raw->setContents('foo bar baz');
    }
}
```

Based on this, I think that my controller should be accessible via a `POST` request to: `http://localhost/posttest/test`, but it just gives me a 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try with http://localhost/posttest/test/test

Answer (score 1):

First of all the routing that Magento uses is in the format `http://example.com/route_name/controller/action`. So to use your route `http://localhost/posttest/test` create `Index.php` inside `app/code/Post/Test/Controller/Test` folder. I am sharing the action code for get request below.

`app/code/Post/Test/Controller/Test/Index.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Post\Test\Controller\Test;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "controller action"; exit;
    }
}
```

For post request you need to change the controller above and also need to use the csrf token in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You are Hitting a Get Request in a Controller implemented with `HttpPostActionInterface`

try to change the interface from `HttpPostActionInterface` to `HttpGetActionInterface`

like this

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function execute()
    {
       //TODO do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the pattern that Magento uses :

`http://localhost.com/exmapleroute_name/controller/action`

So to use your route `http://localhost/posttest/test` create Index.php inside

app/code/Post/Test/Controller/Test folder.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers helped me understand the organization/structure for controllers but it turns out that my problem was that I was submitting the POST request from Postman, which wasn't including the CSRF token. I would have expected that a forbidden error would have been returned if it was failing CSRF but it was still just giving me a 404.

I ended up writing the class like this:

```php
class Index extends Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
```

And then submitted the form via my site and it worked.